# Which built-in function should come first in this particular case?

Tags: python, built-in-types

In this particular part of the program, I couldn't really get why the `.startswith` function wasn't the first one to be used:

```
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From ') : continue
    words = line.split()
    print words[2]
```

I mean, wouldn't it be faster than stripping every single line at the beginning? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the first, because your line might end with whitespace. Consider the following strings:

```
"From somebody"
"From "
```

The version you posted above removes the trailing whitespace, leaving `"From somebody"` and `"From"` respectively. For the second string, `startswith` now returns `False` instead of `True` as your version with swapped functions would.

I guess this is some form of verification that there is actual content after the `"From "` part, which - compared to whitespace - does not get stripped away.